# PSEXEC to start calculator on remote server works only when debugging vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, process, psexec

> I'm trying to start calculator on remote server using psexec from an ASP.NET app and it works when debugging but not working when start project normally on release below is my code

```
Dim p As Process = New Process()
    Dim result As String = ""
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c psexec \\servername -u username -p password calc"
    p.Start()
    p.WaitForExit()
```

also the command [psexec \servername -u username -p password calc] works fine when execute it in cmd prompt.

Comment: i figured out also that if debug in IIS Express it works but didn't work in Local IIS !!

Comment: this is supposed to run from a web app? ASP.NET?

Comment: yes @kshkarin its web app

Comment: and the IIS app pool user running this app has permission to launch a remote process on the target machine? When it's running in IIS Express it's running with the local user permissions.

Comment: @kshkarin how i can know ?

Comment: from the IIS Manager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525920(v=vs.90)

Comment: i made it administrator but nothing chaged, its permission issue but i dont know where.

Comment: made what administrator? the identity running the app pool needs to have remote execution privilege on the remote machine, when running it from VS in IIS Express it'll use the logged in user privileges.

Comment: it's possible to enable impersonation in IIS if it's running with `<authentication mode="windows">`

Comment: i did everything but nothing happened and when i set app pool identity to administrator is gives me error "Access is denied"

Comment: issue solved by changing application pool identity to administrator